# Replace the values of column with mean which has particular value in other column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[10, -1], [20, 1], [30, -1],[40, 1], [50, 1], [60, 1], [70,-1], [80,-1], [90,-1], [100,1]], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

Calculate the mean of column A whole value is 1 in column B and assign to c, here it is **c=54**. I want to replace only those values of column A which has -1 value in column B and value lesser than c with c value.

**Expected Output:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[54, -1], [20, 1], [54, -1],[40, 1], [50, 1], [60, 1], [70,-1], [80,-1], [90,-1], [100,1]], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get values of `A` by `B==1` in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), get mean and set `A` by compare less like mean only for `B==-1` values:

```
mean = df.loc[df['B'].eq(1), 'A'].mean()
print (mean)
54.0

mask = df['A'].lt(mean) & df['B'].eq(-1)
df.loc[mask, 'A'] = mean
print (df)
     A  B
0   54 -1
1   20  1
2   54 -1
3   40  1
4   50  1
5   60  1
6   70 -1
7   80 -1
8   90 -1
9  100  1
```